# Excel Finding Difference Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Spreadsheet for reference:

[image]
Hi,

So I've got a expense log I use to keep track of expenses that are owed to me, as part of my job I incur business expenses that need to be claimed back, some weeks I'm not paid full amount, so would like a way of finding which items these are.

In the above sheet you'll find a rough version of my log, with the expense claims and the amount, the total should be paid and the amount paid.

Is there a formula which finds which expenses add up to the difference (in this case £29.40) and lists them / identifies them.

Feel free to message if anything is unclear.

Thanks

Comment: Of course it's possible to make, but the question is is it worth it? In many cases there will be more than one answer, in this case there 3 possibilities (and that's only with 5 records), and as this is a kind of a corporate cost reconciliation task I imagine the amount of records will only grow in time.

Comment: Not really,  There is no formula that will do this.  With formulas you need to  know some of the specifics, not be this open ended.  Even vba would be hard pressed to do this accurately, just too many possibilities.  This takes reason to accurately find the answer and Excel is just not that advanced.

Comment: So you would want to have a list with descriptions and amounts? If there is a finite number of possible descriptions, you could do it simply with SUMIFS.

Comment: The (quite long winded) code here works and you could adjust for your needs...

http://www.tushar-mehta.com/excel/templates/match_values/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `Excel 2010` or later, you can use the `Solver add-in`.

Once you have loaded that, it will appear on the `Data tab`.

First, you will want to add two columns in between your current columns `B` and `C`. You can label them Multiplier and Product.

Put the number 1 in `C2:C6`, then place the formula `=B2*C2` in `D2`. Copy this formula down to `D6`, then put the formula `=SUM(D2:D6)` in `D7`.

Open the `Solver add-in`.

The first box is `Set Objective`.

Click in the box, then click on `D7`.

It should appear in the box as `$D$7`.  The next line says To:  `Max`, `Min` or `Value Of`, with radio boxes beside each.

Click on `Value of` and type in your desired value, in this case `29.4`

Next is `By Changing Variable Cells`.  Your range will be `$C$2:$C$6`.

This can be done by typing it in or highlighting the range.

You will see a large text box below labeled `Subject to the Constraints`.

You will want to `add 3 constraints` using the Add button:

- `$C$2:$C$6 <= 1`
- `$C$2:$C$6 = integer` (`int` in the middle drop down)
- `$C$2:$C$6 >= 0`

Then click `Solve`.

Some values in column `C` will change to `0`, causing the values in column `D` to do the same.

Those that remain will add up to the `29.4`.

You can also use conditional formatting to highlight the cells that remain at 1.